# How do I return a reference to the first element of a named range?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'd like to return a reference to the first element (i.e. upper left cell) of a named range in a Google Sheet.  I don't want the cell value itself, but rather, the reference "address" of the cell, preferably in A1 notation.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you want to do with it. You can get the actual address with

```
=address(row(NamedRange1),column(NamedRange1))
```

or just

```
=cell("address",NamedRange1)
```

but you can also use INDEX to get a reference which you can use in a formula e.g.

```
=sum(index(NamedRange1,1,1):index(NamedRange1,3,3))
```

to give the sum of the area between the first row and column and third row and column of the range.

Comment: Thanks!  `index(NamedRange1,1,1)`  gives me exactly what I needed.